# how to check an Ajax request really sent from server?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am using Laravel, and I have a form and I want to send it to the server using Ajax (with Jquery), How can I check that an Ajax request really is from server. As you know there are lots of way of **CSRF attack** and sending from from Ajax is really easy and user can send it from anywhere. (even without having a form).

Is there any way to check with php (or Laravel)?

Is Sending a form data(s) using Ajax is not dangerous?

Comment: never worked with Laraval but having a look at google with 'laravel csrf token ajax' could help you. There are a lot of tutorials for that problem...

Comment: @aronadaal thanks. can you share the links

Comment: @LASH https://www.google.com  . Do some research man

Comment: @Letmesee do you know what does LASH MEANS?

Comment: @LASH If you like to debate about the meaning of english words, please move on to [http://english.stackexchange.com](http://english.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has a built-in CSRF Protection for ajax and non-ajax call. See [Laravel Routing](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#csrf-protection).

Answer (score 0):

You can check the ajax request in google chrome developer window then select network tab in which you can see all the request and ajax request name is XHR request

Comment: And this helps in what way exactly?

Comment: if your ajax request is in list then ajax request really sent otherwise not